# Question about cardinality of a base of a topology

Tags: general-topology

I am having trouble expressing in mathematical notation for the hint given in the following question:

Prove that if a space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ has a base $\mathcal{B}$ of cardinality $\alpha$ then the cardinality of $\mathcal{T}$ can not exceed$\ 2^{\alpha}.$  (Hint: Define a surjective function from the set of all sub-families of $\mathcal{B}$ onto $\mathcal{T}.$ Note that the cardinality of the set $X$ itself is of little importance here.)

I am not sure if the surjective function written in the following manner would suffice

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a topology on X, $\mathcal{B}$ be a base for topology $\mathcal{T}$, and let $\ C=\{\mathcal{B}:\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{T}\}$ be defined as the sub-families of $\mathcal{B},$ and let $\ D=\{\mathcal{V}:\mathcal{V}\in\mathcal{T}\}.$

The surjective function from $f:C\rightarrow\ D$ be defined as $f(\mathcal{B})=\mathcal{V}$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $(X,\mathcal{T})$, of size $\kappa$, then there is a standard injection $F:\mathcal{T} \to \mathscr{P}(\mathcal{B})$ defined by

$$F(O) = \{B \in \mathcal{B}: B \subseteq O\} $$

where the right hand side is a well-defined subset of $\mathcal{B}$, so an element of $\mathscr{P}(\mathcal{B})$ which has size $2^\kappa$.

$F$ is injective:

By the definition of a base, $\bigcup F(O)=O$ (all members of $F(O)$ are subsets of $O$ so the union is too, and if $x \in O$ there is at least some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq O$ so that $B \in F(O)$ and $x \in B \subseteq \bigcup F(O)$ which shows the reverse inclusion)

and so $F(O)=F(O')$ implies $O=O'$ showing injectivity of $F$.

This shows that $|\mathcal{T}| \le 2^\kappa = 2^{|\mathcal{B}|}$ as required.

Alternatively, the argument above also shows that the map $\mathcal{B'} \to \bigcup \mathcal{B}'$ from $\mathscr{P}(\mathcal{B})$ to $\mathcal{T}$ is surjective ($F(O)$ is a pre-image for $O$), which is another way to show the same inequality of cardinals.

Comment: Henno, thank you for your added solution.  I did not know injectiveness is involved for the question.

Comment: @SethMai That's because $|X| \le |Y|$ iff there is an injection from $X$ to $Y$. How else would *you* prove the inequality of cardinalities of sets? Assuming AC, it would be equivalent to there being a surjection from $Y$ to $X$ and then cardinalities are linearly ordered as well. I always assume AC when working with cardinals.

Comment: is it always good thing to assume AC or its equivalence when working with cardinals?  Actually, are there some common mathematical situations where you have to explicitly make clear that you are using AC.  I never really understand say why in linear and abstract algebra, theorems for vector spaces and ring theory, why AC is needed.

Comment: @SethMai Sometimes it's considered important mark that a theorem depends essentially on AC. This stems from times when a proof without it was considered better than one with it, but such feelings seem to be rarer nowadays. I use it without any "remorse". You need it because in abstract algebra you cannot show **any** vector space has a basis without it. In many concrete cases you can show that without AC, but it's well-known that $\Bbb R$ as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$ has a basis only if we assume (a version of) AC. Likewise for every ideal being contained in a maximal ideal.

Comment: @SethMai Before Gödel we did not even know whether AC could give a contradiction with the rest of the axioms (ZF). Now we know they're equiconsistent (if ZF is free of contradictions, so is ZFC and of course vice versa). So much of the early suspicion on AC (there has been a lot of debate on it on the philosophical level) is gone.

Comment: but math majors don't get taught how to recognize under what and which circumstances AC can and should be used explicitly, do you know?

Comment: @SethMai No, that's a matter of taste and style. Just use it whenever the proof idea you have  leads to it. Don't worry, really.

Answer (score 3):

Your map $f$ should be defined on $\mathcal{B},$ not on the power set of $\mathcal{T}$. As is written, you've just proven that the cardinality of $\{\mathcal{B}\}$ is the same as the cardinality $\{\mathcal{V}\},$ whatever the latter symbol refers to, but both of these sets have one element, so that isn't even an interesting statement.

So let's take $U\in \mathcal{T}$ and let's figure out what to do with it. By definition of a base, for every $x\in U$ there exists some $B_x\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq U$ (similar to how a ball works in a metric space). Then, $U=\cup_{x\in U} B_x$. This gives us a clue as to what to do, since $\{B_x|x\in U\}$ is clearly an element of the power set $2^{\mathcal{B}}$.

So let $f:2^{\mathcal{B}}\to \mathcal{T}$ be defined by $f(A)=\cup_{B\in A} B$. By what we've just proven, then $U=f(A),$ where $A=\{B_x|x\in U\}$. Hence, $f$ is surjective and the cardinality of $\mathcal{T}$ cannot be greater than that of $2^{\mathcal{B}}$.

I don't know if you can prove this without using the axiom of choice (which featured quite heavily in our construction of $f$), but my gut feeling says probably not.

Comment: thank you for clarifying that up for me.  I was having really having a hard time translating the hint into math notation.

Comment: So many odd-sounding things are known to be consistent with the negation of Choice that I suspect that the existence of an injection from $T$ into $2^B$ might not be provable without Choice....+1